# jquery ui component to get a directory location

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am new to frontend development. I need to get a directory location from user. User will be uploading the postgresql installation location like (C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\8.3). Is there any jquery component to achieve this other than textbox ? I tried will file upload where we can upload only file and cant input a directory location ? Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the issue with <input type="file" ?

Comment: can <input type="file" can be used to get a directory path ? or only file ?

Comment: you can't get the full file path if you use <input type="file" because of browser security

Comment: *"I need to get a directory location from user"*  Since that is a security issue, perhaps you are better off describing the feature you intend to offer the user, so we can suggest better strategies.

Comment: I need to get the location of postgresql installed. Since it will be difficult in traversing the file system (Windows/Linux/mac) to get the installed location, the alternate design is to get the location from user. So I am looking for a UI component to get the installed location of PostgreSQLfrom user.

Comment: *"I need to get the location of postgresql installed."*  Again, that is not a application feature.  What are you trying to ***achieve*** by all this?  What will the end result do ***for the user?***

Comment: I have to access postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf file, which will be in postgresql_installed_loc/bin directory and need to update some configuration settings using java code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, you can't get full path with file using HTML elements.

Try this plugin:
http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/

It shows directory structure to choose file from. You might build full path this way.